# How do I create a list with 256 elements?

Tags: python

I've started teaching myself Python, and as an exercise I've set myself the task of generating lookup tables I need for another project.

I need to generate a list of 256 elements in which each element is the value of `math.sin(2*i*pi/256)`. The problem is, I don't know how to generate a list initialized to "dummy" values that I can then use a for loop to step through and assign the values of the `sin` function.

Using list() seems to create an "empty" list, but with no elements so I get a "list assignment index out of range" error in the loop. Is there a way to this other than explicitly creating a list declaration containing 256 elements all with "0" as a value?

Comment: "`math.sin(2pi/256)`"  I doubt that.  I think it's `math.sin(2*i*math.pi/256) for i in range(256)`.  Please correct your question.  Also, please use paragraphs so that we can actually parse your question.

Comment: @Bitrex: Can you maybe accept an answer to mark the question as resolved?

Answer (score 10):

Two answers have already shown you how to build your list at a single stroke, using the "list comprehension" (AKA "listcomp") construct.

To answer your specific question, though,

```
mylist = [None] * 256
```

is the simplest way to make a list with 256 items, all `None`, in case you want to fill it in later.

If you start with an empty list, call its `.append(...)` method to add each item at the end.  A loop doing nothing but `append` on an initially-empty list is what normally gets replaced with a more concise listcomp.

Of course, for the task you actually state,

```
mylist = [math.sin(2 * math.pi/256)] * 256
```

would be by far the best approach -- no sense computing a `sin` 256 times when the argument's always the same (daringly assuming that what you *say* is what you *mean*;-).

Comment: Alex, is this Dummy Python Arrays for Dummies?

Comment: @Peter, the author of "Python for Dummies" is an old friend of mine and the book is pretty good indeed.  This is just a simple attempt to explain a few of the "facts of life" about Python lists.

Comment: *Facts of life?!* Are you saying there's a book about, *gasp!*, snake sex? Perhaps it even has a `list` of positions.

Answer (score 5):

```
my_list = [math.sin(2 * math.pi/256) for i in xrange(256)]
```

Comment: +1, since this does produce, as its result, what the OP so explicitly says he wants (rather than something utterly different like the other equally-upvoted answer).  But it's still absurd to do SO much work when `[math.sin(2 * math.pi/256)] * 256` would do the same job hundreds of times faster!-).

Answer (score 1):

> I need to generate a list of 256
>   elements in which each element is the
>   value of math.sin(2*math.pi/256)

To answer your question literally:

```
my_list=[math.sin(2*math.pi/256)]*256
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
l = []
for i in range(256):
    l.append(math.sin(2*math.pi/256))
```

This is an iterative `for` loop that keeps adding the same value to the end of the list 256 times

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, everyone.  I did make a mistake in the specification I posted for the question, in that the value of each element in the list needs to be the sin of the angle *incremented* by 2*pi/256 each time.  The code that works for me in that case is:

```
li = [math.sin((2*math.pi/256)*i) for i in xrange(0,256)]
```

Comment: So accept answer that worked for you by clicking on tick sign on left margin.